# Global Exception Handler in Struts 2

Tags: java, exception, struts2, struts

I have a hybrid Struts 1 and Struts 2 application. My Struts 1 application has the following exception handler:

```
<global-exceptions>
    <exception type="java.lang.Exception" handler="myClass" />
</global-exceptions>

<global-forwards>
    <forward name="error" path="/error.jsp" module="/" />
</global-forwards>
```

I'm trying to accomplish a similar mapping in my Struts 2 part of the application. Here is what I have right now:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="myErrorHandler" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">myErrorAction</param>
    </result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
     <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="myErrorHandler" />
</global-exception-mappings>

<action name="myErrorAction" class="myErrorAction">
      <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

However, whenever I test out my error handler, I get an infinite loop (myErrorAction keeps calling itself). Is there a better way to setup a global exception handler in Struts 2? My action has custom code which creates special log entries and builds the error message to display to the user on the jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that your `myErrorAction` (or your `error.jsp`) is not throwing an Exception? That would account for the infinite loop.

One should take much care that the resources that handle exceptions are totally sure in this regard.

Comment: Here is the current code for myErrorAction: public String execute() { return "error"; } Maybe I should add some print statements.....

Comment: I added print statements and they printed successfully. The infinite looping continued though.

Comment: On further research, I tried using the same action to handle struts 1 and struts 2 exceptions. The problem was that my Struts 1 handler extends a Struts 1 exceptionHandler instead of the Struts 2 action class. This was causing the recursive exception loops.