# Struts 2 - How to redirect exceptions of type Exception to a particular page, but not handle a particular exception?

Tags: exception, struts2, struts

I wish to redirect all errors of type `Exception` to the result "**error**". For that, I did this :

```
<global-exception-mappings>
          <exception-mapping result="error" exception="java.lang.Exception"></exception-mapping>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

But I don't want to handle a particular exception, specifically the `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException` which should be allowed to propagate further. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Issue related : [dont let struts auto catch Exception and send 500 error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3811)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Use `instanceof` operator and rethrow desired exception from exception handler.</strike>

I managed it with an interceptor (here is what I used to try it out):

```
package com.kenmcwilliams.interceptor;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Rethrower implements Interceptor{
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation){
        System.out.println("Start rethrower!");
        String result = "success";
        try {
            result = invocation.invoke();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Rethrower.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Object exception = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().findValue("exception");
        if (exception instanceof RuntimeException){
            System.out.println("DOING RETHROW!");
            RuntimeException e = (RuntimeException)exception;
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println("After rethrower!");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the struts.xml (to save time looking up struts dtd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <package  name="kenmcwilliams"  namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="rethrower" class="com.kenmcwilliams.interceptor.Rethrower"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="rethrow-stack">
                <interceptor-ref name="rethrower"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <global-results>
            <result name="error" >/WEB-INF/content/error.jsp</result>
        </global-results>
        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
        </global-exception-mappings>
        <action name="mybomb" class="com.kenmcwilliams.kensocketchat.action.Bomb">
            <interceptor-ref name="rethrow-stack"/>
            <result>/WEB-INF/content/bomb.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Finally the action (it just throws a runtime exception):

```
package com.kenmcwilliams.kensocketchat.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Bomb extends ActionSupport{
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as u said, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736618/global-exception-handler-in-struts-2 and it said "infinite recursion detected" which is kind of expected as we keep throwing the same exception that we are catching and it keeps getting caught again and again. I don't want Struts to handle this particular exception.

Comment: Sorry about that, rethinking.

Comment: You have added the Rethrower interceptor at the top of the interceptor stack, so the default ExceptionMappingInterceptor will get a chance to execute before that and it will map even the RuntimeException to "error.jsp". Rethrower might not even get a chance to see this exception. Am I right ?

Comment: No both will execute (this might not be what you want, but generally this will let you show the user the error and then I assumed the exception was not to change the view but to do some cleanup). I think the ExceptionMappingInterceptor somehow places the exception into the valuestack (have not checked this). Because rethrower checks if there is an object keyed with "exception" in the valuestack, reversing the order would not work. If you want to NOT do both then I think you'll need to implement your own ExceptionMappingInterceptor and replace it.