# Handling multiple <error-page> definitions in web.xml

Tags: exception, error-handling, struts, web.xml

On my web.xml, I have this:

```
 <error-page>  
       <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>  
       <location>/error.do</location>   
 </error-page>  
 <error-page>  
       <exception-type>org.apache.struts.chain.commands.UnauthorizedActionException</exception-type>  
       <location>/unauthorized.do</location>  
  </error-page>
```

The problem is: When I have an UnauthorizedActionException, the action that is called is "error.do" (the Throwable action).
If I comment the  of Throwable, hhen I have an UnauthorizedActionException, the action is ok, but when I put the throwable, it goes to wrong action.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313279/struts-2-how-to-redirect-exceptions-of-type-exception-to-a-particular-page-bu

Answer (score 1):

`UnauthorizedActionException` inherits from `java.lang.Throwable` so it would be valid for it to be handled by your first error page definition.

Try re-ordering the definitions to be...

```
 <error-page>  
       <exception-type>org.apache.struts.chain.commands.UnauthorizedActionException</exception-type>  
       <location>/unauthorized.do</location>  
  </error-page> 
 <error-page>  
       <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>  
       <location>/error.do</location>   
 </error-page>
```

**[Edit]** following your comment

Then I would suggest removing these entries form your web.xml and [configure your exception handlers in your struts-config.xml](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/exception-configuration.html) instead. You may get away with defining your exception handlers in the global scope. Something like this ...

```
<global-results>
    <result name="login" type="redirect">/Login.action</result>
    <result name="Exception">/Exception.jsp</result>
    <result name="UnauthorizedActionException">/UnauthorizedActionException.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="org.apache.struts.chain.commands.UnauthorizedActionException" result="UnauthorizedActionException"/>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="Exception"/>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

Comment: The same is happening to me. If I remove the declaration for Throwable then it works for my other exception, otherwise it redirects to the throwable age. No matter the order of the declarations.